# max() lambda function doesn't work correctly

Tags: python

i have list of floats. I want to find max value of list which is less then b

```
valuex_x = [1.9,1.11,1.17,1.19,2.12,2.14,2.18,2.20,3.10,3.15,3.17,3.22,5.11,5.12,]


b = input()
print(max(value_list_x, key = lambda x: x < float(b)))
```

So for example when b = 4 it returns 1.9 instead of 3.22
Why? How to fix?

Comment: You're *comparing* values based on `x < float(b)`. This will turn all values into bools for comparison and then find "the largest bool", whatever that means. You'll want to separate things here: filter the list, then find the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom key function returns `True` or `False`, so `max()` returns first value where it evaluates `True`. Filter the list first, then apply `max()`:

```
valuex_x = [1.9,1.11,1.17,1.19,2.12,2.14,2.18,2.20,3.10,3.15,3.17,3.22,5.11,5.12,]
b = 4

print( max(v for v in valuex_x if v < b) )
```

Prints:

```
3.22
```